# Overlapping legend: How to put geopandas legend next to the map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am using `geopandas` and `contextily` to plot building data (polygon) from OpenStreetMap. The problem is, the legend is overlapping with the map. **Is there any way to put the legend next to the map? or outside the map?** or plot the map without legend, but export the legend separately from the map? I don't want it overlapping.

I hope the image helps.

here's my code to produce the map (I know the code is a little different, but it yields the same map):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
%matplotlib inline

buildings = gpd.read_file("buildings.shp")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(9,9))
buildings.to_crs(epsg=3857).plot(column='building', ax=ax, cmap="Paired", legend=True)
ctx.add_basemap(ax, url=ctx.providers.Esri.WorldTopoMap)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[IMAGE OF The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwiMB.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **plt.legend()** and with the parameters of **bbox_to_anchor** and  **loc**

check out this documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html

and this example:https://www.delftstack.com/howto/matplotlib/how-to-place-legend-outside-of-the-plot-in-matplotlib/